# Change row after certain column

Tags: excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet where only column A - G is visible. The rest is hidden.
Rows 1 - 200 is visible, the rest is hidden. I use a scanner to scan 2D Datamatrix code to enter values from column A to G. When entering the value in column G the G cell stays active. My goal is to move to next row after the insertion of the value in the G cell. I thought there was a simple built in feature in excel for this but I haven't found it. I'm using Microsoft Excel 2016 Professional for this.

Answer (score 0):

1.Click the Insert tab.
2.In the Tables group, click Table.
3.Specify that the range has header cells and click OK